# How to include a dash(#) in a htaccess rewrite rule?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

As you know the dash introduces a comment

how can I make this valid?

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /#$1 [R=301,NC]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [*NE* flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/rewrite_flags.html#flag_ne):

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /#$1 [R=301,NE]
```

By the way: The `#` is only the start of a [comment](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/configuring.html#syntax) if used at the start of a line:

> Lines that begin with the hash character "#" are considered comments, and are ignored. Comments may not be included on a line after a configuration directive.

Answer (score 1):

You can't manager data after # by apache. Even facebook handles redirection for data after # by javascript.

If I'm wrong, please someone correct me, some years ago this problem drives me crazy.

Comment: You can’t read the fragment of a URI on the server side as it’s not sent to the server but just used locally. But the server can response with a redirect with a URI with fragment.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It's like I've found out some times ago.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `#` with `\%23`, and that should do the trick, or use the `[NE]/noescape` flag.